# Bubbling Event for ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-bubbling

I'm having Parent and child element. I want to show the context menu of child only(not parent one). I'm capturing ContextMenuOpening event of parent and child. No action to be performed on child event it's just for testing purpose that event is trigger as per bubbling rule, but on parent i want to handle the event so that it didn't show up. Following is the xaml code for that.

**Xaml Code**

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Aqua" Height="20" Width="100" ContextMenuOpening="Border_ContextMenuOpening">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" ContextMenuOpening="PART_ContentHost_ContextMenuOpening"/>
                    <Border.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Border.ContextMenu>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>                
        </TextBox.Template>
    </TextBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void PART_ContentHost_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Border_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

**Issue**

In this case when i click on textbox the event bubble and is handled at border. But the contextmenu of child doesn't show up. Any Idea?

Comment: You have already handled the event and stooped bubbling of event by adding the code `e.Handled=true`

Comment: @AbinMathew that's true. But the issue is that event is handled at parent element. The event of child should fire. My question is that why child event not fired? My ultimate goal is to show child contextmenu, not parent contextmenu